# How to get the proper response code of InsertAsync?

Tags: exception, aspnetboilerplate

I have a `CreateClassification` API which is used to insert data into database table. There is unique constraint in table, So If I try to insert same record it gives the below response.

```
{
"result": null,
"targetUrl": null,
"success": false,
"error": {
"code": 0,
"message": "An internal error occurred during your request!",
"details": null,
"validationErrors": null
},
"unAuthorizedRequest": false,
"__abp": true
}
```

API:

```
await _classificationrepository.InsertAsync(classobj);
```

But failure reason is not clear by this response message, because there could by many reason for a failed insert, So is there any way to get the proper reason of failure.

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_ClassificationCode'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Classification'. The duplicate key value is (02).
The statement has been terminated.
```

As suggested, I have tried this, but it has no impact on api response:

```
Task Createxyz(XyzInput input);

public async Task Createxyz(XyzInput input)
    {
        try
        {
            await _xyzrepository.InsertAsync(classobj);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw new UserFriendlyException("hello");
        }
    }
```

Hitting the below url:

```
http://localhost:22742/api/services/app/xyz/Createxyz
```

I have one more doubt, how my `Createxyz` gets converted into api?, means how abp provides routing to `Createxyz` method, so that end user can call this api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABP hides exception details from users. For instance, this is not a good error message to show to a users (because of user experience and security of your application):

`Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_ClassificationCode'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Classification'. The duplicate key value is (02).`

So, you should handle specific types of exceptions yourself (I don't know the exception type in your case) and throw a `UserFriendlyException` yourself.

`UserFriendlyException` is a specific type of exception so ABP directly show exception message to the end user.

**EDIT**

Example:

```
try
{
    await _repository.InsertAsync(...);
    await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch(SqlDuplicateKeyException ex)
{
    throw new UserFriendlyException("Duplicate name..!");
}
```

I don't know if there is such a SqlDuplicateKeyException. To understand it's type, catch general Exception and check it's type or message. This is basic C# practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **IUnitOfWorkManager** .
Check out the code below;

```
 public class MySampleAppService : ApplicationService
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager;

        public MySampleAppService(IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager)
        {
            _unitOfWorkManager = unitOfWorkManager;
        }

        public async Task Createxyz(XyzInput input)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
                {
                    await _xyzrepository.InsertAsync(classobj);
                    unitOfWork.Complete();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new UserFriendlyException("hello this is the exception message: " + ex.Message);
                //note: check if there's inner exceptions you need to flatten all the inner exceptions !
            }
        }
    }
```